# PostgreSql and Django How to store large data (6GB+) per entry or row

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, blob

Recently, I'm working with one project (Django + PostgreSQL), I store record as normal text type after encode to base64. After awhile I came to realize that storing record that I store some record size is around 6GB which is over max-size of 1 GB in text of postgres. I try to search around and got some recommend of using [BLOB in Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB). I further research more in how to use it with sample ,but seem no answer.

Anyone use to Experience it, really appreciate ?

Comment: What are you storing? You could use a bytea, but maybe whatever this is doesn’t actually need to be in the table at all.

Comment: @Ryan As I read from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB, bytea is limit to 1GB. Do you have any good sample about this?

Comment: You didn’t answer the question.

Comment: I storing kind of text from base64. It's kind of modeling from Machine Learning in which I use pickle to dump it

Comment: Are you sure Pickle is a good choice of serialization format? Anyway, put it in a file and put the path to the file in your database.

Comment: Yes, I use to try it. It's working fine. but as I research more, I got advise that storing it as file will lead to problem of overhead, and scalability if we frequently prediction for particular model. Do you have any suggest over it?
I want to store Stream Pickle not File object Pickle

Answer (score 1):

6gb per record?!! you're doing it wrong. If the record is 6gb then it should not be in the database, you should be storing that on disk and have the database record point to the path of that file.

Comment: Yes, I used to do it, but I got recommended from others that it will lead to problem of overhead and scalability. It's not that all the time record is that big maybe only 1 among 1000, but anyways, system has to handle it. Could I know is there a good ways to store data in HDD and stream it back across multiple server in Network ?